# How to query/filter all posts by one user ? (MEAN stack)

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

**CODE:**

Controller

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('users')
    .controller('MyArticlesController', MyArticlesController);

  MyArticlesController.$inject = ['$state', '$window', 'UsersService', 'Authentication', 'Notification', 'ArticlesService'];

  function MyArticlesController($state, $window, UsersService, Authentication, Notification, ArticlesService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.user = Authentication.user;

    vm.articles = ArticlesService.query();


  }
}());
```

**SITUATION:**

This code works perfectly fine and displays all posts ever created.

**QUESTION:**

How can I query only the posts created by the currently authenticated user?

What would the syntax look like?

Comment: Why the downvote ? Tell me what's wrong and I'll do my best to make the question clearer.

Comment: vm.user = Authentication.user;
    vm.articles = ArticlesService.query();
Can return only the currently authenticated user articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll pass wanted username in request, then you can use `find` as follows:

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Article.find({'user.username': req}).exec(function (err, articles) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(422).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(articles);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Add filter to controller:

```
vm.authFilter = function(item) {
  return item.author == vm.user;
}
```

and use it in `ng-repeat`:

```
<a ng-repeat="article in vm.articles | filter: vm.authFilter" ...>
```

(assuming that `article.author` is author of article)

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/bhz3qvef how it works.

Edit:

In your case it's:

```
vm.authFilter = function(item) {
  return item.user.displayName == vm.user.displayName;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, it did not work :/ I updated my question to show how I implemented your solution. Tell me if you see anything wrong.

Comment: add `console.log(item.author); console.log(vm.user);` before return in `vm.authFilter`

Comment: So `vm.authFilter` returns always true or false?

Comment: All empty. Means false.

Comment: See added jsfiddle. Mechanism works. You need to see why it always return false. Any logs from my prev comments?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question with a screenshot of the logs. Apparently, the objects are actually slightly different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134821/discussion-between-lukasz-and-coder1000).

Comment: What about comparing `displayName` (see last update)?